# cant retrieve data using XMLHttpRequest()

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

My goal is to create a JavaScript program that uses the XMLHttpRequest object to retrieve information from an HTML file and display the response to the user without reloading the page.

Once a button is clicked, the data should be displayed.

The issue is my code can't access the data in the HTML file. The JS file and the HTML file are placed in the same folder too so how do I solve this?

**JS code:**

```
//button to get data
var btnGet = document.querySelector("#btnGetData");
btnGet.addEventListener('click', getData);

//Create getData function
function getData(){
    //Create XMLHttpRequest object
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    
    //onreadystatechange
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
        document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        alert("did it");
    }else{
        alert("error");
    }
};
    //Create the request
    xhttp.open("GET", "data.html", true);
    
    //Send the resuest
    xhttp.send();
}
```

**Error received from browser:**
[image]

Comment: The problem is, that XHR doesn't work with file protocol. Install a local server to your machine, then you can use http(s) protocol.

Comment: If your main goal is to keep the data in a separate file, put it in a separate script in tabular / array form, like `const = data [ ... ];`, that way you can include it like a regular script above your main script and simply reference `data`.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript can't read local files on the client's filesystem. That will only work if the files are stored on the server.